# Is possible to use a Database for storing machine-learning data ? if so, how?

Tags: mongodb, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, database

I am new to machine learning. I would like to set a machine on my server and using a database for storing data learnt.

```
var colorClassifier = new NeuralNetwork();

colorClassifier.trainBatch([
    {input: { r: 0.03, g: 0.7, b: 0.5 }, output: 0},  // black
    {input: { r: 0.16, g: 0.09, b: 0.2 }, output: 1}, // white
    {input: { r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 1.0 }, output: 1}   // white
    ]);

console.log(colorClassifier.classify({ r: 1, g: 0.4, b: 0 }));  // 0.99 - almost
```

The codes for machine learning frameworks are something like this, but i want that 'colorClassifies' is logically stored in my Database and not in the memory, so that i can train this machine during time without losing old data about old trains. I don't really know how these frameworks internally work, but i think it's possible to do something like what i am asking for. thank you

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Persist the trained model on disk?

Comment: yes, this is my purpose @ziggystar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I don't really know how these frameworks internally work"*

However the framework works, training a classifier means finding a set a weight values such that the classifier works well (usually this means minimizing the sum of squared errors). So, a trained classifier is essentially a set of real numbers. To persist the classifier you need to store these numbers to your database.

Each weight can be described by four numbers:

- The layer number (integer): The first layer is the input, the rest are the hidden layers (usually one or two), in the order they appear.
- From, to (integers): Since each weight connects two nodes, the serial number of these nodes inside each layer
- The value of the weight (usually real number)

If, for example, you have a weight with value 5.8 going from the 3rd node of the 2nd layer to the 5th node of the next layer, you can store it in a table

layer: 2
from_node: 3
to_node: 5
value: 5.8

By repeating this for all weights (a simple for loop) you can store the trained network in a simple table. I don't know how your framework works, but normally there will be a member function that returns the weights of the trained network in list or hashmap format